# Поле даты в модель джанго

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Делаю to-do list на Django. Как в модель добавить поле где можно будет установить и сохранить дату до которой нужно будет сделать таск. Ну т.е например какое то задание нужно сделать до 23.10 и человек устанавливает 23.10. Перепробовала все и ничего не идет. Желательно максимально просто без подключения JQ и Bootstrap

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User




# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: `end_date  = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'крайний срок')`

Comment: не работает. django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: base_task.end_date

Comment: миграции........

Comment: `./manage.py makemigrations`, `./manage.py migrate` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/

Comment: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'end_date' to task without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: это после makemigrations